# Get N tweets from list in twitter using linq2twitter

Tags: c#, linq, twitter

I'm doing something like this to get the tweets from a list in twitter:

```
twitterCtx = new TwitterContext();


var Tweets = from tweet in twitterCtx.List
             where tweet.Type == ListType.Statuses && tweet.OwnerScreenName == osn &&
             tweet.Slug == listName  &&
             tweet.Count == 100
             select tweet.Statuses;


return Tweets.SingleOrDefault().Where(x => x.CreatedAt > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-numOfDays)).GroupBy(p => p.User.Name).Select(g => g.First());
```

I'm getting the latest tweet from a user in the list using the last bit:

```
.GroupBy(p => p.User.Name).Select(g => g.First());
```

how can i get the latest 5 tweets by them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't used the Twitter API, but the obvious first thought is to change it to:

```
.GroupBy(p => p.User.Name).Select(g => g.Take(5));
```

Then you'd get the tweets with something like:

```
foreach (var group in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Tweets for {0}", group.Key);
    foreach (var tweet in group)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("  {0}", tweet.Text); // Or whatever
    }
}
```

Comment: I get this error when i use Take: Error 579 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<LinqToTwitter.Status>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<LinqToTwitter.Status>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: @raklos: Well you need to change the return type as well, presumably. You haven't shown enough context for us to be able to fix that for you.